# Как можно перенести цифру из EditText во вторую MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

У меня есть две `Activity`, в первой `EditText` и `Button`, мне нужно передать цифру во вторую `Activity` кнопке `button`.

Кнопка должна нажиматься то количество раз, которое задано в `EditText` на первой `Activity`.

Я гуглил и ничего не нашел кроме `setExtra()`.

Можно ли использовать `setExtra()` для передачи цифры из `EditText`?

Comment: Хоть интент, хоть переменная static

Comment: Да хоть SharedPreference